# Set baud rate to esp8266 at 9600

Tags: arduino-uno, at-command, esp8266

I brought an esp8266-12, it works at 115200 baud rate. I sometime connect it to arduino uno to work for some projects. It would be easy if I connect esp8266 with arduino at 9600 baud rate. The AT version is 0.25. I googled and saw the AT command set documentation it had a command to set baud rate. It was like

```
AT+ UART_DEF=<baudrate>,<databits>,<stopbits>,<parity>,<flow control>
```

But the problem is I don't know what these parameters are and how to set the parameters so that is works at 9600 baud rate with arduino.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a long time of searching, I found the parameters to work with Arduino at 9600 baud rate.

```
AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0
```

Comment: I thought my esp8266 didn't support this command because querying the current values via `AT+UART_DEF?` returned `ERROR`. But setting the new baud rate still worked.

Answer (score 0):

To change the baud rate of esp8266, use this command.

```
AT+CIOBAUD=9600
```

Easy and simple. Command can be sent through serial communication from Arduino UNO.